# Textarea is null when posting via AJAX with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I try to post this textarea, it sends nothing and obviously returns nothing for that field.

All other input fields are fine.

I've read and everyone says to make sure .value is added after getelementid, which I was doing anyhow, so I'm not sure what is wrong.

I'm using Bootstrap 3, in case that matters.

**Update:** I just did a test and hard-coded text into the textarea field. That successfully passed. But any text that I type into the form does NOT get passed. I think this might be a Bootstrap 3 bug, perhaps.

Does anyone else know?

**Javascript:**

```
var http_request = false;

function show_hint(p_hint_text, p_span) {
    document.getElementById(p_span).innerHTML = p_hint_text;
}

function makePOSTRequest(url, parameters, SpanName) {
    http_request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
            http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }

    http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                //alert(http_request.responseText);
                result = http_request.responseText;
                document.getElementById(SpanName).innerHTML = result;
                document.getElementById(StatusName).innerHTML = 'Ready';
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    };
    http_request.open('POST', url, true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    alert(parameters);
    http_request.send(parameters);
}


function Contact(obj, SpanName, StatusName) {
    var curDateTime = new Date(); //For IE
    var poststr = "gid=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("gid").value) +
        "&tid=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("tid").value) +
        "&cid=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("cid").value) +
        "&recid=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("recid").value) +
        "&item_ip=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("item_ip").value) +
        "&item_userid=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("item_userid").value) +
        "&item_author=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("item_author").value) +
        "&fromajax=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("fromajax").value) +
        "&action=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("action").value) +
        "&active=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("active").value) +
        "&message=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("message").value);
    var SpanName = SpanName;
    var StatusName = StatusName;
    //alert (SpanName);
    alert(poststr);
    makePOSTRequest('http://fakedomain.com', poststr, SpanName);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="ContactFormSpanQXBIAHOBEU25">
<span id="statusQXBIAHOBEU25">
<form role="form" action="javascript:Contact(document.getElementById('ContactForm'),'ContactFormSpanQXBIAHOBEU25','statusQXBIAHOBEU25'); show_hint('Sending Data, Please Wait...', 'statusQXBIAHOBEU25');" method="post" name="ContactForm" id="ContactForm">
<input name="gid" id="gid" type="hidden" value="SDZOAYLTDV26">
<input name="tid" id="tid" type="hidden" value="ZBSAGNSCFM55">
<input name="cid" id="cid" type="hidden" value="2">  
<input name="recid" id="recid" type="hidden" value="QXBIAHOBEU25">
<input name="item_IP" id="item_ip" type="hidden" value="555.555.555.555">
<input name="item_userid" id="item_userid" type="hidden" value="YCGLNBFZPD13">
<input name="item_author" id="item_author" type="hidden" value="YCGLNBFZPD13">
<input name="fromajax" id="fromajax" type="hidden" value="1">
<input name="action" id="action" type="hidden" value="add">
<input name="active" id="active" type="hidden" value="1">
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
<input name="Submit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" value="Submit" />
</form>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: But there is in fact no value in the textarea. Do you write something in it before sending?

Comment: I see that you are using `Bootstrap 3`, which requires jQuery if you want to use their javascript plugins. Is there a particular reason why you want to accomplish this through plain JavaScript and not a more cross-browser solution (jQuery)?

Comment: @Florian, the data would be sent after they fill in the textarea.

Comment: @lightswitch05 My ajax solution is not a plug-in, which is why I'm using vanilla javascript to post data via AJAX.

Comment: @FlorianPellet I just did a test where I hard-coded text into the text area field and it passed! But any text that I type into the form does NOT get passed. This is weird.

Comment: Are you running any other JS that might alter the textarea? Such as WYSIWYG widget?

Comment: @Quentin, yes. Bootstrap 3 does that with placeholder text. I removed the WYSIWYG editor completely so I can test this so it must be the Bootstrap placeholder JS, among other Bootstrap issues, perhaps.

Comment: Do you get any of your alerts at all? I'd suggest you strip your code of everything but the minimum (keep the form, the button, and the textarea). Try to get that working (first just to `alert` you with its value, then to pass it through the submit `action` function, then to POST it). And only then, add the rest.